# How can I tell if a set of app engine tasks have all completed?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

If I have a loop that enqueues say 100 tasks and each one of those tasks potentially enqueues a task, how can I tell if all tasks have completed?

I've thought about this problem using ShardedCounters. Once each task is completed, I could increment a counter then check to see if count == 100. Of course that falls apart with tasks spawning their own tasks unless I get into this recursive counting scenario. I'm not sure it's a good idea to go down that rabbit hole because it appears the sharded counters are not atomic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the new AppEngine [pipeline API](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/). It's a way of chaining together expensive tasks, and notifying when they're complete. There's a also great [video from the Google IO conference](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/high-throughput-data-pipelines-appengine.html) which demonstrates it.

Comment: Watching the Slatkin talk on YouTube right now. If it leads to a solution, I'll mark this as it. Thanks!

Comment: The pipeline API is great, but I do not think it works with general recursion--only tail recursion.

Comment: Yes this was the answer. Pipeline API is incredible! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996760/writing-to-an-appengine-blob-asynchronously-and-finalizing-it-when-all-tasks-com

Comment: Pipeline API: Google code is dead, code moved here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-pipelines

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the scenario, you can test to see if any tasks (matching some pattern or having a certain ID/etc) are currently en-queued using the REST API:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/rest.html#method_taskqueue_tasks_list